# splitting a String after x tabs

Tags: java, string, split

I have to separate a value from a .txt file.
I created a LineNumberReader and used the .split("\t") to separate the words, but I only need the second last value (q-value).
Is there an option to specify the .split()?

This is my .txt file

```
test_id gene_id gene    locus   sample_1    sample_2    status  value_1 value_2 log2(fold_change)   test_stat   p_value q_value significant
XLOC_000001 XLOC_000001 TC012951    ChLG10:20399-27664  naive   BttO    NOTEST  0   0.0498691   1.79769e+308    1.79769e+308    0.210754    1   no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`String#split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method, to stop splitting after the column you wish to extract and get the String you want in one line of code:

```
    String line = "A\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF"; // tab separated content
    int column = 3; // specify the column you want (first is 1)
    String content = line.split("\t", column + 1)[column - 1]; // get content 
    System.out.println(content);  // prints C (3rd column)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] array = someString.split("\t");
String secondToLast = array[array.length - 2];
```

Comment: this will split on _slash t_, not on _tab_

Comment: the value of interest is always at the same array position. To get this value isn't that hard but as it is I produce a bunch of strings which aren't needed. I was looking for a way to reduce the string output

Comment: @Mirar - Might want to put that in your question; don't have ESP (especially at this time of the morning :) )

Answer (score 0):

Given you have this line:

```
XLOC_000001 XLOC_000001 TC012951    ChLG10:20399-27664  naive   BttO    NOTEST  0   0.0498691   1.79769e+308    1.79769e+308    0.210754    1   no
```

and you want `1` (the penultimate element)

You can use this expression:

```
String s ="XLOC_000001 XLOC_000001 TC012951\tChLG10:20399-27664\tnaive\tBttO\tNOTEST\t0\t0.0498691\t1.79769e+308\t1.79769e+308\t0.210754\t1\tno";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\t|^)([^\t]*?)\t[^\t]*?(?:\\n|$)").matcher(s);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Or, wrapped in a function:

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\t|^)([^\t]*?)\t[^\t]*?(?:\\n|$)");
public static final String getPenultimateElement(String line) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
    if(m.find())
        return m.group(1)
    return null; // or throw exception.
}
```

Or, where the caller can specify the separator:

```
public static final String getPenultimateElement(String line, String separator) {
    separator = Pattern.quote(separator);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:" separator + "|^)([^" + separator + "]*?)" + separator + "[^" + separator + "]*?(?:\\n|$)").matcher(line);
    if(m.find())
        return m.group(1)
    return null; // or throw exception.
}
```